# postinstall webpack not working on Heroku

Tags: node.js, heroku, webpack, post-install

I'm using Heroku to host my app and webpack to build it.

Basically, I'm trying to deploy my app, but it doesn't work at all.

The postinstall doesn't seem to occur since when I load the page it's missing the file `bundle.js` (which is built via webpack).

Here is my `package.json` scripts:

```
"main": "server.js",
"scripts": {
    "dev": "webpack-dev-server --devtool eval --content-base build/ --colors --hot",
    "start": "node server.js",
    "postinstall": "webpack -p --config webpack.prod.config.js --progress"
}
```

When I push my project to heroku, there is no error displayed during the process. I can see in the console that it's running my postinstall:

> remote:    > pistou@1.0.0 postinstall /tmp/build_80dea0f9774d7a9a5f8f33ee9c913bca
>   remote:    > webpack -p --config webpack.prod.config.js --progress

Here is my whole `webpack.prod.config.js` file:

```
var path = require('path');
var webpack = require('webpack');
var node_dir = path.resolve(__dirname, 'node_modules');

module.exports = {
    entry: [
        'unveil',
        path.resolve(__dirname, 'app/main.js')
    ],
    output: {
        path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'dist'),
        filename: 'bundle.js',
        publicPath: '/'
    },
    module: {
        loaders: [
            {
                test: /\.jsx?$/,
                include: path.join(__dirname, 'app'),
                loader: 'babel'
            },
            {
                test: /\.scss$/,
                include: path.join(__dirname, 'app/styles'),
                loader: 'style!css!sass'
            },
            {
                test: /\.(png|jpg)$/,
                loader: "file"
            },
            { test: /\.woff(\?v=\d+\.\d+\.\d+)?$/,  loader: "url?limit=10000&mimetype=application/font-woff" },
            { test: /\.woff2(\?v=\d+\.\d+\.\d+)?$/, loader: "url?limit=10000&mimetype=application/font-woff" },
            { test: /\.ttf(\?v=\d+\.\d+\.\d+)?$/,   loader: "url?limit=10000&mimetype=application/octet-stream" },
            { test: /\.svg(\?v=\d+\.\d+\.\d+)?$/,   loader: "url?limit=10000&mimetype=image/svg+xml" },
            { test: /\.eot(\?v=\d+\.\d+\.\d+)?$/,   loader: "file" }
        ]
    },
    plugins: [
        new webpack.NoErrorsPlugin(),
        new webpack.ProvidePlugin({
            $: "jquery",
            jQuery: "jquery",
            "window.jQuery": "jquery",
        }),
        new webpack.ContextReplacementPlugin(/moment[\/\\]locale$/, /(fr|en)$/),
        new webpack.DefinePlugin({
            "process.env": {
                "NODE_ENV": JSON.stringify("production")
            }
        }),
        new webpack.optimize.UglifyJsPlugin({
            minimize: true,
            compress: {
                warnings: false
            }
        }),
    ],
    resolve: {
        alias: {
            "unveil": "./app/statics/jquery.unveil.js",
        }
    },
};
```

Comment: Is `webpack` correctly installed ? If it's in your `devDependencies`, you need to `heroku config:set NPM_CONFIG_PRODUCTION=false`. You should remove the `webpack.NoErrorsPlugin` in production, so that your build doesn't fail silently and you could see the errors you might be missing

Comment: @topheman You were right there was a silent error running. Thanks !

Comment: thanks! setting that config made my build pass. this should be in the docs

Comment: Sorry to bother on an old post, but @topheman it'd be great if you posted an answer to the question, it helped me a lot :^)

Answer (score 0):

The --progress flag leads to a high number of print statements and log messages which heroku doesn't like and makes the process crash. Try to run without the --progress flag